# High latency time in pgAdmin 4 opening a DB with many tables

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have complex databases (>6000 tables) in my PostgreSQL database. When I open this database in the tree view of the pgAdmin 4, pgAdmin does react very slow and is often in idle. A navigation in the tree is only possible with long latency time.

Is there a way to increase the performance of pgAdmin 4 to improve the performance?

I would like to switch to pgAdmin 4, however this issue keeps me using pgAdmin III 1.22

Comment: You could benchmark the queries that pgAdmin 4 sends and see if the problem is there. If not, it is in the GUI. You should contact the authors.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that, however with pgAdmin III 1.22 it works works smoothly. Thus I blame pgAdmin 4 for it...

Comment: I have the same problems every now and then with pgAdmin 4. Maybe the limitation is in the browser, not coping with the amount of info. pgAdmin 4 has a kickass UI, but for smooth usage I still use pgAdmin III or even psql in the console. If you find a workaround, please post it here ;-)

Comment: I don't even have a database on my server. So why is it taking forever to look that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrolling through the tables is much smoother now with version 3.3 of PGAdming 4. However it takes a few seconds until the list of tables is expanded.

Updating the PGAdmin 4 was the solution for me.